# solution of a matrix using orthogonal vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

let be the Matrix A  ...

- A is hermitian $A=A^\dagger$
- ALL the eigenvalues of A are non zero

then could i solve the linear system $Ax=B$

by using the eigenvectors in this form ?, the solution would be

$ x= \sum_{j}\frac{c_{j}}{\lambda _{j}} V_{j} $

here  $ C_j $is the scalar product of the vectors $ C_{j} = (B, V_{j}) $

and $ A V_{j}= \lambda _{j}V_j $ is an eigenvector

Comment: Yes. $~~~~~~~~$

Comment: Small note: for this to work, the $V_j$ eigenvectors should be normalized, i.e., multiplied by a constant so that $\| V_j \| = 1$.